# Flood fill NumPy Array `numpy.ndarray`, i. e. assign new value to element and change neighboring elements of the same value, too

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, flood-fill

Another, similar post called [Flood Fill in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839947/flood-fill-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1) is a very general question on flood fill and the answer only contains a broad pseudo code example. I'm look for an explicit solution with `numpy` or `scipy`.

---

Let's take this array for example:

```
a = np.array([
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
])
```

For selecting element `0, 0` and flood fill with value `3`, I'd expect:

```
[
    [3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1],
    [3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
]
```

For selecting element `0, 1` and flood fill with value `3`, I'd expect:

```
[
    [0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0],
    [0, 0, 3, 2, 3, 3],
    [0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0]
]
```

For selecting element `0, 5` and flood fill with value `3`, I'd expect:

```
[
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3],
    [0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
]
```

This should be a fairly basic operation, no? Which `numpy` or `scipy` method am I overlooking?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flood Fill in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839947/flood-fill-in-python)

Comment: @Goyo That's a pseudo-code and don't see that working with array without wholesome changes to the accepted solution. How do you propose to use the accepted solution there to solve it here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Module `scikit-image` offers the built-in to do the same with [`skimage.segmentation.flood_fill`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.segmentation.html#skimage.segmentation.flood_fill) -

```
from skimage.morphology import flood_fill

flood_fill(image, (x, y), newval)
```

Sample runs -

```
In [17]: a
Out[17]: 
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])

In [18]: flood_fill(a, (0, 0), 3)
Out[18]: 
array([[3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1],
       [3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])

In [19]: flood_fill(a, (0, 1), 3)
Out[19]: 
array([[0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 2, 3, 3],
       [0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0]])

In [20]: flood_fill(a, (0, 5), 3)
Out[20]: 
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3],
       [0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

**Approach #2**

We can use [`skimage.measure.label`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.label) with some `array-masking` -

```
from skimage.measure import label

def floodfill_by_xy(a,xy,newval):
    x,y = xy
    l = label(a==a[x,y])
    a[l==l[x,y]] = newval
    return a
```

To make use of SciPy based `label` function - [`scipy.ndimage.measurements.label`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html), it would mostly be the same -

```
from scipy.ndimage.measurements import label

def floodfill_by_xy_scipy(a,xy,newval):
    x,y = xy
    l = label(a==a[x,y])[0]
    a[l==l[x,y]] = newval
    return a
```

Note : These would work as in-situ edits.

Comment: Note that it's `(y,x)` not `(x,y)`